# Pandas - How to drop rows based on a unique column value where another column value is a minimum and handling nulls?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with something like the following:

| index | order_id | cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123a | 123 | 5 |
| 123b | 123 | None |
| 123c | 123 | 3 |
| 124a | 124 | None |
| 124b | 124 | None |

For each unique value of order_id, I'd like to drop any row that isn't the lowest cost. For any order_id that only contains nulls for the cost, any row for an order_id can be retained.

I've been struggling with this for a while now.

```
ol3 = ol3.loc[ol3.groupby('Order_ID').cost.idxmin()]
```

This code doesn't play nice with the order_id's that have only nulls. So, I tried to figure out how to drop the null's I don't want with

```
ol4 = ol3.loc[ol3['cost'].isna()].drop_duplicates(subset=['Order_ID', 'cost'], keep='first')
```

This gives me the list of null order_id's I want to retain. Not sure where to go from here. I'm pretty sure I'm looking at this the wrong way. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: if specific order_id contain only nan in cost, then drop it ?

Comment: I need to keep one row per order_id, even if its nan

Answer (score 1):

You can use `transform` to get the indexes with min `cost` per `order_id`. We additionally need `isna` check for the special `order_ids` that have only `NaN`s:

```
order_mins = df.groupby('order_id').cost.transform('min')
df[(df.cost == order_mins) | (order_mins.isna())]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried this and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm getting a KeyError on order_id. I'm new to stackexchange so let me know if you need any more info from the error.

Comment: I think I got it actually, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can (temporarily) fill the NA/None with `np.inf` before getting the idxmin:

```
ol3.loc[ol3['cost'].fillna(np.inf).groupby(ol3['order_id']).idxmin()]
```

You will have exactly **one** row per order_id

output:

```
  index  order_id  cost
2  123c       123   3.0
3  124a       124   NaN
```